# Weird / Funny ouput after beautifulsoup web scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I thought this would be funny and interesting to share. I ran into a weird situation which I have never encountered before.

I was fooling around with pythons beautifulsoup. After scraping https://www.amazon.ca i got the strangest output at the end of the HTML.

[image: meow??]

Can anyone tell me if this is intentional from the developers of amazon? Or is this something else ?[image: MEOW! HAHA]

FYI here is the code I used to show it has nothing to do with me

```
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as re


# ********Below is the soup used to gather the HTML************

url = "https://www.amazon.ca"
page = re.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: If you view the page source in a browser - it's there as well... so...

Comment: I do receive the entire HTML from the soup. So  I guess the developers just wanted to have some fun ?

Comment: ha ha ha yes just for fun, i think so!

Answer (score 0):

So, Amazon doesn't allow web scraping on their websites. They may change the HTML content for web scraping programs. For me, the HTML just said: "Forbidden".
If you want to get data from Amazon, you will probably need to use their API